# Get only one child with max value of a property

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework and I have the following code:

```
var query = this._dbContext.Set<Parent>()
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(p => p.IsActive.Value)
    .Include(child=> p.Children)                   
    as IQueryable<Parent>;
```

This would give me all the children. Also, children have a property named VersionNumber. How should I edit the query above so as it returns only one child, which is the one with the Max Value of VersionNumber.

Pls note VersionNumber is an INT incremented by 1, for each record of a child for each Parent.
Parent     Child     Child.VersionNumber
1              1         1
1              2         2
2              1         1
2              1         2

Comment: . OrderByDescending(a=>a.VersionNumber).Take(1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a projection of your results.

```
var query = this._dbContext.Set<Parent>()
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(p => p.IsActive.Value)
    // not necessary since you're selecting children in your projection below .Include(child => p.Children) 
    .Select(p => new Parent
    {
        Children = p.Children.OrderByDescending(c=> c.VersionNumber).Take(1),
        p.OtherProperty,
        p.AnOtherProperty,
        p.YouGetTheIdea // manual select the properties of parent you require
    }); // Not necessary  as IQueryable<Parent>
```